# Multi Object JSON containing static and dynamic data

Tags: json, database, d3.js, time-series

I have more than 1 million rows of data in excel and I want to convert it to JSON so i can visualize it using D3js and other web based applications. Data is comprised of two subsets:

- General information of each data points, including geographical location, ID.... (static data not changing once it is written)
- Monthly measurements at each data point. This data set updates monthly once new data arrives

This is how data looks like:

> ID: 2411976, State: Texas, County: DEWITT, Latitude: 29 Longitude:-96,
>   Data: 11/1/2013   27.516; 12/1/2013   15.3566; 1/1/2014   27.6418;
>   2/1/2014  13.45; 3/1/2014 11.21; 4/1/2014 20
>
> ID: 2321771, State: Texas, County: DEWITT, Latitude: 29 Longitude:-96,
>   Data: 11/1/20134  19; 12/1/2014   21; 1/1/2015    30; 2/1/2015    50; 3/1/2015    10;
>   4/1/2015  5
>   .....

Is it possible to wrap all data points in one JSON document that contains both temporal data and static data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible, as you can represent arrays/objects in a nested structure, like this:

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "id": 2411976, 
        "state": "Texas",
        "county": "DEWITT", 
        "latitude": 29,
        "longitude":-96,
        "data": [{
            "date": "2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 27.516
        }, {
            "date": "2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 15.3566
        }, {
            "date": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 27.6418
        }, {
            "date": "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 13.45
        }, {
            "date": "2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 11.21
        }, {
            "date": "2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2321771, 
        "state": "Texas",
        "county": "DEWITT", 
        "latitude": 29,
        "longitude":-96,
        "data": [{
            "date": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 19
        }, {
            "date": "2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 21
        }, {
            "date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 30
        }, {
            "date": "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 50
        }, {
            "date": "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 10
        }, {
            "date": "2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 5
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is just one way of doing it. Depending on what the consumer of this data expects as input, you could adapt accordingly.